# Compute an orthonormal coordinate system - GPS coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm working on a representation of the Earth and moving on it.

I use geolocation (latitude+longitude) and the direction in which I'm moving is the angle between, in the tangent plane to the Earth where I am, a North-South axis (remaining away from poles, so) and a vertex representing the forward direction.

I would like to compute an orthonormal coordinate system at the viewer position.
The up vertex is easy, I just have to normalize the position (as the center of the Earth is (0,0,0)).
Then I would like to have a forward vertex and a left vertex (in the tangent plane, so). What is the easiest way to get them both?

Thanks for your help

Cathy L.

Answer (score 0):

Cathy, do you have any experience with the vector cross-product in 3D?
The relevance of the cross-product is that it can find orthogonal directions for you.  The local 3D axes you want to superimpose locally on a geolocation requires you to construct 3 axis directions (local east, local north, and local_z (up)).
Each of these directions is expressed in a geocentric coordinate system (your reference global coordinates).  In these global coordinates (for stationary, non-rotating Earth), the 3D axes are:

• origin - at the geocenter of the Earth

• + x-axis points out to geolocation [ 0, 0 ] (near Nigeria)

• + y-axis points out to geolocation [ +90, 0 ] (in Indian Ocean)

• + z-axis points out North Pole

Getting back to cross-products, they result in a direction mutually perpendicular to the two input vectors.  How can this be used to get a local East at [Lon, Lat]?

What if you take the cross-product using the local "up"? (which you brilliantly figured out is just the normalized direction vector equivalent to [Lon, Lat]

d_local_z = [ cos(lat)cos(lon),    cos(lat)sin(lon),   sin(lat)  ]

What direction could you cross it with?  How about the global Z direction (Earth center to North Pole) [ 0 0 1] ?  Using the right hand rule (do you know this rule?), the resulting vector pointing to local East is [ 0 0 1 ] X d_local_z.

Also, because of the way the cross-product gives a variable length result vector, the result has to be normalized before using it as a direction vector (or as an axis definition).

d_local_east = normalize( [ 0 0 1 ] X d_local_z )

The d_local_north direction can be computed as a cross-product, using what you've got so far for d_local_z and d_local_east.  See if you can figure out (using right hand rule) whether you want

d_local_north = normalized ( d_local_east X d_local_z )

or

d_local_north = normalized ( d_local_z X d_local_east )

Now, that you have the 3 local axes as direction vectors, you're very close to being able to convert from global cartesian coordinates --> local cartesian coordinates in a rotated frame at geoloc [ lon, lat ].

And, once you have that conversion, you can represent motions as vectors, and convert these using coordinate rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to assume a spherical Earth.
The actual Earth is closer to a slightly flattened ellipsoid,
which GPS receivers generally assume.
In the ellipsoid model, the vertical vector is usually not exactly
in the same direction as the location vector.

Assuming a spherical Earth,
if $(x,y,z)$ is the vector from the center of the Earth to a point
on the Earth's surface, where the three axes form a right-handed system
with the $z$ axis is parallel to the 
Earth's rotational axis (pointing north), 
we can obtain an orthonormal system of
vectors aligned with the local compass directions at this location
using formulas derived [in another answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1210570/139123)
Provided that $x^2+y^2 \neq 0,$ let
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$
and
$$\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$$
Then the "up" vector is
$$\hat r = \left( \frac xr, \frac yr, \frac zr \right)$$
(I think this is what you meant by "normalizing the position").

The "east" vector is
$$ \hat \varphi = \left( \frac{-y}{\rho}, \frac{x}{\rho}, 0 \right) $$
and the "north" vector is
$$ \hat \theta =
 \left( \frac{-xz}{\rho r}, \frac{-yz}{\rho r}, \frac \rho r \right).$$

To get vectors aligned with a particular direction of travel,
let the direction be at an angle $\psi$ 
clockwise from the due north direction.
Then the "forward" vector can be obtained by combining the "north" and
"east" vectors,
$$ F = \hat \theta \cos\psi + \hat\phi \sin\psi,$$
and the "leftward" vector is
$$ F = \hat \theta \sin\psi - \hat\phi \cos\psi.$$
The "up" vector, of course, is the same as before.